# Issue with ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Inside an iframe I have the following script:

```js
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.href) {
    let link = e.target.href;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/newOrigin",
      data: {
        "link": link
      },
      type: "POST",
      success: function (response) {
        parent.document.getElementById("oframe").srcdoc = response.site;
        parent.document.getElementById("oLink").href = link;
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

---

Which does not work. The prevent default doesnt do it's job, meaning the event itself isnt being triggered. I believe the issue is with the second line in the ajax success function, since the code below works perfectly fine (srcdoc changes and console is logged).

```js
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.href) {
    let link = e.target.href;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/newOrigin",
      data: {
        "link": link
      },
      type: "POST",
      success: function (response) {
        parent.document.getElementById("oframe").srcdoc = response.site;
        console.log("Hello");
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

oLink is the id of an a tag element (hyperlink) and oframe is the id of another iframe inside the parent of the iframe where this code is.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT:  The site has two iframes and each have a title above them(with each title having an href of the page displayed in each iframe). When a link is clicked in the first iframe, an ajax request is sent with the link and the response has the html of that page which is sent to be displayed in the 2nd iframe (1st line in success function). I now want to change the href of the words above the 2nd iframe to be the link of the link clicked in the 1st iframe. So the two titles and two iframes are inside the same parent component (same level) and the script is inside the first iframe.

The html used is base.html + index.html from here (iframes and titles in index.html): https://github.com/MohamedMoustafaNUIG/AnnotatorVM/tree/master/app/templates

EDIT2: Apparently, the success function is isolated from the rest of the code, meaning it doesnt have access to the "link" variable. I solved this by returning the link in the response and accessing it from there. But the event is still not triggering :(

Comment: so, on every click for every hyperlink tag, you change the `#oLink` href value? even if you clicked on `#oLink` itself? It is hard to understand the use-case (which is also important for the context of the question). can you please elaborate about the use case?

Comment: There is another iframe with words (h4) above it. I want the 2nd iframe to change contents and the title above it to change href when a link is clicked in the 1st iframe. The ajax response contains the html of the clicked link. The event wont trigger for oLink as it is not inside the first iframe (where the script is).

Comment: @Thatkookooguy the site has two iframe and each have words above (each having an href of the page displayed in each iframe). When a link is clicked in the first iframe, an ajax request is sent with the link and the response has the html of that page which is sent to be displayed in the 2nd iframe (1st line in success function). I now want to change the href of the words above the 2nd iframe to be the link of the link clicked in the 1st iframe.

Comment: can you please add the additional info to the question itself?

thanks!

Comment: if you have any HTML to share, even better :-)

Comment: @Thatkookooguy done :)